# AngularJS Select Not Binding To Ng-Model

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

My angular select isn't binding. I can tell the value is correct, but the select isn't updated. Why is not binding if the value is there?

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-app>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="colorId"ng-options="color.id as color.name for color in colorList">
        <option value="">--Select a Color--</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="Select()"></input>
```

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.colorList = [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'red'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'blue'
    }, {
        id: '3',
        name: 'green'
    }];

    var colorId = 3;
    $scope.colorId = colorId;
    alert($scope.colorId);

    $scope.Select = function () {
        var colorId = 2;
        $scope.colorId = colorId;
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ky5F4/23/

Comment: See my answer. You are still using '1', '2', '3' for ids in your object. You need to set $scope.colorId to '1', '2', or '3' to have it bind, or you can update each id to be number (i.e. 1, 2, 3) instead of string.

Answer (score 7):

you need to change the id to a string when doing Select

```
$scope.Select = function () {
    console.log('select fired');
    var colorId = 1;
    $scope.mySelection.colorId = colorId + "";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxkwfo0s/2/

next you should use a property of an object rather than just a scope variable, this will ensure proper model binding

```
ng-model="mySelection.colorId"
```

where the object could be something simple

```
$scope.mySelection = {colorId : colorId };
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors with your code:

1. You are using colorList as your model in ng-options, but you are calling it datasets in your controller.
2. You use strings for the id, but set the $scope.colorId to a number.

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky5F4/24/) changing ids to numbers and changing $scope.datasets to $scope.colorList

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.colorList = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'red'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'blue'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'green'
    }];

    var colorId = 3;
    $scope.colorId = colorId;
    alert($scope.colorId);

    $scope.Select = function () {
        var colorId = 2;
        $scope.colorId = colorId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your ng-model be an object, specifically one of the objects that are already in your $scope.colorList.  If you do that you should be able to avoid the post-processing you're doing in the click handler.

So your select will look like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedColor" 
        ng-options="color.name for color in colorList"></select>
```

One gotcha is that if you have an object in your controller that looks JUST LIKE your red object, like`$scope.selectedColorObj = { id : '1', name:'red' }` and set the select's ng-model to that option, it won't work.  Angular will see that you're setting to the ng-model to an object that's not actually in your data source and add an extra option with `value="?"`, so I use `$filter` in this case to grab the matching member of the array:

```
 $scope.colorId = '3';
 $scope.selectedColor = $filter('filter')( $scope.colorList,{ id: $scope.colorId})[0];
```

See  http://jsfiddle.net/ky5F4/92/